# How to get value of a function in defaultValue attribute of an InputBox in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want my **defaultValue** attribute of an input box to be bound by a reactive function.

```
getSelectedColor(e) {
    return 'red'; // just for sake of simplicity now
}
```

and here is my virtual DOM (HTML) defined inside the render() function

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.getSelectedColor.bind(this)} />
```

I have declared the function inside the constructor of the component class.

The result of the above implementation is my input box showing value 
**function () { [native code] }**

This happens even if I write inline function for defaultValue attribute

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={()=>{return 'red'}} />
```

How to get the value returned from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assign the value to `defaultValue` attribute, so instead of binding the method call that method, like this:

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.getSelectedColor()} />
```

Binding is not required here.

Note:

**defaultValue:** this will assign the initial value only, means one time during the initial rendering.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain a little bit more, why and what happened here?

Comment: reason is, when we define binding of any method it will return a method (and allow us to use correct this keyword inside that method),  someone should call that method to get the value from that,  and in this case you want to assign the value returned by function you don't want to return a method :)

Comment: assigning method is required when specifying any event like `onChange, onBlur` etc they expect method not value there we need to assign method and if we want to use `this` then `bind` that method, like this: `onChange={this.getSelectedColor}` it will return the method that will get called on change of input, but when you write `this.getSelectedColor()` it will return the value, hope now you will get the point :)